# Prove that $\dim(U_1 \cap U_2 \cap ... \cap U_k) \geq n-k$ and find a case where the equality doesn't hold

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space of dimension $n$. Let $1 \leq k \leq n$ and consider $U_1,...,U_k$ distinct subspaces of $V$, all of dimension $n-1$

> a) Prove that $\dim(U_1 \cap U_2 \cap ... \cap U_k) \geq n-k$

> b) Give (at least) an example where the equality on $\dim(U_1 \cap U_2 \cap ... \cap U_k) \geq n-k$ doesn't always hold.

My attempt

a) To do the proof, I am using the dimensional theorem

$$\dim(U \cap W) = \dim(U) + \dim(W) - \dim(U + W)$$

And [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

Let me show you what I have so far.

$\underline{\text{The base case} \ k=1}$

$$\dim(U_1) \geq n-1$$

---

I think this is not necessary for the proof, but I also checked $k=2$. Using the dimensional theorem I get

$$\dim(U_1 \cap U_2) = \dim(U_1) + \dim(U_2) - \dim(U_1 + U_2)$$

Where

$$\dim(U_1) \geq n-1$$

$$\dim(U_2) \geq n-1$$

$$\dim(U_1 + U_2) \leq n$$

Thus

$$\dim(U_1 \cap U_2) \geq n-2$$

---

$\underline{\text{Induction step}}$

Here I assumed that $\dim(U_1 \cap U_2 \cap ... \cap U_k) \geq n-k$ holds and proved that it also holds for $k+1$ by means of the dimensional theorem.

$$\dim((U_1 \cap U_2 \cap ... \cap U_k) \cap U_{k+1}) = \dim(U_1 \cap U_2 \cap ... \cap U_k) + \dim(U_{k+1}) - \dim((U_1 \cap U_2 \cap ... \cap U_k) + U_{k+1})$$

Where

$$\dim(U_1 \cap U_2 \cap ... \cap U_k) \geq n-k$$

$$\dim(U_{k+1}) \geq n-1$$

$$\dim((U_1 \cap U_2 \cap ... \cap U_k) + U_{k+1}) \leq n \ \ \text{due to} \ (U_1 \cap U_2 \cap ... \cap U_k) + U_{k+1} \subseteq V$$

Thus

$$\dim((U_1 \cap U_2 \cap ... \cap U_k) \cap U_{k+1}) \geq n-k-1$$

Which is the statement for $k+1$.

$\underline{\text{Conclusion}}$

Since both the base case and the inductive step have been proved as true, by mathematical induction the statement $\dim(U_1 \cap U_2 \cap ... \cap U_k) \geq n-k$ holds for every natural number $k$.

Is my proof OK?

b) Here I did not find any case breaking the equality; I tried with $k=3$, $k=4$ and so on and I always get

$$\dim(U_1 \cap U_2 \cap U_3) \geq n-3$$

$$\dim(U_1 \cap U_2 \cap U_3 \cap U_4) \geq n-4$$

$$...$$

So what am I missing here?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Also, it is not needed to check the $n=2$ case.

Comment: Checking for $k=3$ and $k=4$, while you've proven the inequality for every integer $k$ is futile, you're supposed to find concrete examples where the inequality is strict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof looks fine.

Consider $\mathbb{R}^3$, and three planes which intersect in a single line. Then $n=3$ and $k=3$, but the dimension of the intersection subspace is $1$.